# Edge's weight in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm new in neo4j. 
Im' looking to construct my graph by displaying weights on relationship.
Here is my command:

```
CREATE (origin)-[c:CONNECTED_TO { frequency: row[2] }]->(destination)
```

But I see just CONNECTED_TO

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the type of relationship, and choose the property whose value will be displayed on the edge. Also, you can adjust color and size.

[ http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization ]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the Neo4j browser, you have to click on the relationship to see the properties.

Comment: Yes, I did this but is it possible to display it on edge as label?

Comment: Good question - I would also like to display the property of a relationship